# AppleScript syntax error

Tags: function, applescript, syntax-error

I trying to output a list of todo items from the Mac app Things using AppleScript.

But I get a syntax error:
Expected expression but found “to”.

Since Things uses the name "to dos" and AppleScript doesn't like this, since `to` is a reserved keyword. It works without a problem if the repeat code is directly inside the `tell` statement and not in the function handler.

Is there any way around this?

```
set output to ""

on getTodos(listName)
    repeat with todo in to dos of list listName
        set todoName to the name of todo
                set output to output & todoName
    end repeat
end getTodos

tell application "Things"
   getTodos("Inbox")
   getTodos("Today")
end tell
```

Is this even possible to do it like this?
And is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this is readily doable.  The problem is that outside the `tell application "Things" ... end tell` block, AppleScript doesn't know what things would be special inside it, and doesn't even both to look.  All you need to do, then, is move the `tell` block within `on getTodos(listName) ... end getTodos`:

```
on getTodos(listName)
  tell application "Things"
    repeat with todo in to dos of list "Inbox"
      set todoName to the name of todo
      set output to output & todoName
    end repeat
  end tell
end getTodos
```

You may also be able to replace `tell` with `using terms from`; I think that should work.  Also, you never use `listName`—did you mean to replace `"Inbox"` with `listName`?

You should, however, be able to replace `getTodos` with the single line

```
on getTodos(listName)
  tell application "Things" to get the name of the to dos of list listName
end getTodos
```

This sort of shortcut is one of the things AppleScript is good at.  Also, note that this new version doesn't modify `output`, but just returns the list; I'd argue that's a better decision anyway, but you can always do `set output to output & ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that AppleScript does not know you are trying to use Things-specific terminology in your handler. Try putting the `repeat` within a `using terms from application Things` block, like so:

```
on getTodos(listName)
    using terms from application "Things"
        repeat with todo in to dos of list "Inbox"
            set todoName to the name of todo
                    set output to output & todoName
        end repeat
    end using terms from
end getTodos
```

Comment: This works, but I think putting it into a `tell` block makes for cleaner code.